# Reunion with the loved one after death and in next life

Tags: rebirth, death, reincarnation, love, life-after-death

My spiritual bonding and connection are very strong with my lovely mother who has passed away. We both have tremendous love for each other.

1. Can we be reunited again in the next life? Can she be born as my daughter/son & Can I be born as her son/daughter again?
2. After my death and before the new birth, can I get to meet and talk with my mom (as the Tibetan book of the dead and many NDEs suggest you can meet the loved one after death)

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is answered by the following suttas.

> There the Blessed One said: "From an inconstruable
> beginning comes transmigration. A beginning point is not evident,
> though beings hindered by ignorance and fettered by craving are
> transmigrating & wandering on. A being who has not been your mother at
> one time in the past is not easy to find... A being who has not been
> your father... your brother... your sister... your son... your
> daughter at one time in the past is not easy to find.
>
> "Why is that? From an inconstruable beginning comes transmigration. A
> beginning point is not evident, though beings hindered by ignorance
> and fettered by craving are transmigrating & wandering on. Long have
> you thus experienced stress, experienced pain, experienced loss,
> swelling the cemeteries — enough to become disenchanted with all
> fabricated things, enough to become dispassionate, enough to be
> released."
> [SN 15.14-19](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn15/sn15.014.than.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [Jataka Tales](https://suttacentral.net/pitaka/sutta/minor/kn/ja), such as the [Katthahari Jātaka](https://suttacentral.net/ja7/en/chalmers?reference=none&highlight=false) & [Dasaratha Jātaka](https://suttacentral.net/ja461/en/rouse?reference=none&highlight=false), report the Buddha's family members were also family members in past lives; who were reunited as family members in their future lives.

Answer (score -1):

I feel hesitant writing this. First of all, you are lucky to have had a loving mother.

But please remember, the love that you have for her arose somewhere in time and thus is prone to decay and dissipation. It is a formation (*sankhara*) ,and like all formations, is ultimately impermanent, unsatisfying and devoid of self. I understand that it may be very strong such that it seems permanent to you right now, and the most beautiful and the most important thing ever.

If you can make yourself see clearly in the present moment the arising and the changing of this love towards your mother, you may see the 3 marks in it and get free from it. This is much easier said than done and I myself am in the same situation as you, but please let's have faith that it will happen slowly but surely. See it this way: if your mother could/can see clearly, she would rather want you to be free of craving/suffering than to be born as her son again.

Hope that wasn't too harsh and hope it helped. Be well